# Java - Change data type when using Getters & Setters

Tags: setter, getter

As I stumbled across Encapsulation while learning Java. One of the benefits of using Getters and Setters, according to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm, is:

"The users of a class do not know how the class stores its data. A class can change the data type of a field and users of the class do not need to change any of their code."

But I'm not quite sure what this mean. Does it mean that a:

```
private String name;
```

can be changed to:

```
private int name; ?
```

I would be appreciate if someone could give an example regarding to this.

Comment: you mean what will happen if user enter integer value instead of string ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought it meant. But I see that one of the things I can do is change non static variable to static variable. I'm still not sure what else I can do with it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example if there are only a fixed number of possible names, then maybe the class would change from:

```
class Thing
{
    private String m_name;
    ....
    public String getName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    ...
}
```

to

```
class Thing
{
    private static String[] POSSIBLE_NAMES = ...

    private int m_nameIndex;
    ....
    public String getName()
    {
        return POSSIBLE_NAMES[m_nameIndex];
    }
    ...
}
```

The point is that the getter indicates that the object has a name and can tell it to you when you ask, but the object is free to store or calculate that name however it likes.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I'm still new to Java, and don't quite understand it. So you can add another variable and change whatever inside the getter?

Comment: You can do whatever you want inside the getter, without changing any of the code that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

> A class can change the data type of a field

I think this is wrong thing.its not data type its *Access Modifiers* when we using private access modifiers that variable visible to the class only. the public methods are the access points to this class's fields from the outside java world. Normally these methods are referred as getters and setters. Therefore any class that wants to access the variables should access them through these getters and setters.no need to change `private String name;` to `public String name;`